# Why do I need to use the new Paging library? (Android Architecture Components)

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

I am really interested in newly introduced Android Architecture Components. But I can't say that I understand what is the 'Paging' library about.

It looks like it's purpose is to provide help with data pagination. But isn't that already an easy thing? Like I can just hold some integer values somewhere in my code and then use them later in my network / room database query.

It's clear that I am missing something here. Please help me understand the need of Paging library

Comment: "But isn't that already an easy thing?" -- not really. "Like I can just hold some integer values somewhere in my code and then use them later in my network / room database query" -- it is unclear to me how holding "some integer values somewhere" will allow a user to scroll through a massive data set in `RecyclerView`, for example. Perhaps you could provide a [mcve] demonstrating your easy approach, and we can compare and contrast it with the Paging library.

Comment: Lets assume we are fetching data from a network api / local database and showing the results in a listview / recyclerview. I will have a final Integer with value 20, this will be the data amount I will fetch from the data source at a time. And another Integer for offset, with initial value of 0. Update offset value as we fetch more data from data source.

Comment: @user6650650 And if you do that the scroll will be janky, since you'd need to load asynchronously and they'd be prevented from scrolling after they reach the end until you've loaded more data.  Paging is solvable on your own, but its a non-trivial problem.  I haven't really looked at their new paging library, so I'm not going to comment on how good a solution it is.  But its definitely something a lot of devs could use help with.

Comment: You need to detect that the user has scrolled close enough to the end of the list to need to fetch data. You need to fetch that data. You need a `RecyclerView.Adapter` that can deal with incremental additions to that data. You need some sort of LRU-style caching rules to get rid of older data (that the user has scrolled past) to limit overall memory consumption. You need to handle the scenario where the user scrolls past your current data before additional data gets loaded. And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paging library is indeed for use with data pagination for a data source, this data source can be as simple as a single table in a database or as complex as multiple tables and multiple network api sources as set out in your own custom data source class.

The pagination library not only provides smooth pagination from your data source, but it also provides seamless background updates to the individual recycler view items already shown. I personally hate calling notifyDataSetChanged when unsure of how many items are being changed, and I look forward to the opportunity to have the currently shown list diffed against the requested list form a background thread, with items individually inserted, removed, and updated where necessary.

The full architecture from the pagedListAdapter to the datasource, perfectly separates each concern (making testing easier), and if followed provides a way for a commonly used (and often poorly implemented) aspect of android to be implemented well. This improves individual software quality, user and developer experience (It's fairly simple), and enhances the android brand as a whole (by improving android software quality as a whole).